# How to run a "bunch of code" all the time when application running or in resume mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I want to check 4 things for my application.

1. GPS ON or OFF for the device (iPhone/iPad)
2. GPS ON or OFF for the running application/ is application allow GPS
3. Push Notification service allow or not for running application
4. Background Refresh service allow or not for running application

If any off them turn off, I want to inform the users to turn it on, when the application is on/running/resume mode. That mean i have to put the `4 methods` in some where which run 24/7 if the application in running or resume mode. I think normally this checking are taking place in `app delegate` file. But i also want to check these for `viewController` class for another project. So, what is the perfect `method name` (for appDelegate and viewController) to call these `4 methods` so that it run continuously?
If any one have the answer, please share with me. 
Thanks a lot in Advance.
 Have a nice day.

Here is the sample code :

```
-(void)LocationServiceChecking
{

}

-(void)SystemServiceChecking
{

}

-(void)PushNotificationServiceChecking
{

}

-(void) BackGroundRefreashServiceChecking
{

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag == 2)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
else if (alertView.tag == 3)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
else if (alertView.tag == 4)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
}
```

These are the 4 methods, i declare (for appdelegate>> didFinishlaunching & for viewController>> viewDidLoad) :

```
[self LocationServiceChecking];
[self SystemServiceChecking];
[self PushNotificationServiceChecking];
[self BackGroundRefreashServiceChecking];
```

Comment: please share attempted code

Comment: ok, let me share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code in the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

It will solve your problem of resuming the application.

You need not to call the methods throughout the application lifetime, you can handle different activities in the following delegates:

For Push Notifications

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```

For GPS - check for GPS on/off, using the following code before executing your code dependent on GPS

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

I hope, it will help you solving your issues. enjoy :)